# papyrOS на ARCHlinux

Tags: linux, archlinux

Пытаюсь установить papyros на арч линукс.

Выводит ошибку при вводе:

```
$ pacman -S papyros-shell
Не найдена цель papyros-shell
```

Как исправить это?

Answer (score 1):

как написано [здесь](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Papyros_shell), надо:

1. добавить в `/etc/pacman.conf` (выше дефолтных репозиториев):

   ```
   [papyros]
   SigLevel = Never
   Server = http://dash.papyros.io/repos/$repo/$arch
   ```
2. выполнить:

   ```
   $ sudo pacman -Syu
   $ sudo pacman -S papyros-shell
   ```

после чего можно будет запускать:

```
$ papyros-session
```

---

в каталоге `http://dash.papyros.io/repos/papyros/` содержится под-каталог только для одной архитектуры: x86_64.

если у вас иная архитектура, то уже собранный пакет поставить из этого репозитория не получится: его там просто нет.

но, как и написано в самом начале по приведённой выше ссылке, можно собрать пакет из исходников с помощью [aur](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR).

вот, например, более краткая инструкция по пользованию *aur*-ом: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/511/31480

Comment: [papyros]
SigLevel = Never
Server = http://dash.papyros.io/repos/$repo/$arch
Куда уже только не вставлял и выше, и ниже. Не выходит

Comment: в каталоге http://dash.papyros.io/repos/papyros/ есть каталог только для одной архитектуры: x86_64. может быть, у вас какая-то другая, не интел? или система стоит 32-битная. проверить битность можно командой `getconf LONG_BIT`.

Comment: Да спасибо, 32-ух битка стоит

Comment: тогда надо воспользоваться aur-ом. я дополнил ответ, приведя необходимые ссылки.

Comment: @sholkingx, как и у меня